# How can I fix these OpenSSL and Rails certificate verify failed errors?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, openssl

At some point I started getting this error while trying to update gems:

> SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

How can you debug and fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

Details how to fix:

`openssl::ssl::sslerror: ssl_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=sslv3 read server certificate b: certificate verify failed`

or

`could not load openssl. you must recompile ruby with openssl support or change the sources in your gemfile from 'https' to 'http'. instructions for compiling with openssl using rvm are available at rvm.io/packages/openssl.`